# Get a mesh node from a transform node in Maya C++ API

Tags: c++, plugins, mesh, maya

I want to get a shape/mesh object under a transform node active in Maya.
If I select and object (e.g. a poly sphere) in Maya, when calling `getActiveSelectionList` method, it returns a transform node, not a shape/mesh one.

I'm getting crazy reading the API classes (`MDagPath, MSelectionList, MFnDependencyNode`) and methods which would achieve that but I can't find a way to do it.

So, I want to get the info (vertex coordinates) of a selected/active poly object in Maya GUI through C++ API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to get an MDagPath leading to the transform and then use `.extendToShape` or `.extendToShapeDirectlyBelow()` to get the shape node. Then you need to get an `MFnMesh` from the shape and use that to get to the vertices.

Here's the python version, which is all I have handy.  Apart from syntax it will work the same way in C++ :

```
# make a selectionList object, populate ite
sel_list = MSelectionList()
MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(sel_list)

# make a dagPath, fill it using the first selected item
d = MDagPath()
sel_list.getDagPath(0,d)

print d.fullPathName()
# '|pCube1" <- this is the transform
d.extendToShape()
print d.fullPathName()
#  "|pCube1|pCubeShape1" < - now it points at the shape

# get the dependency node as an MFnMesh:
mesh = MFnMesh(d.node())

# now you can call MFnMesh methods to work on the object:
print mesh.numVertices()
# 8
```

Comment: Thank you, theodox. It's exactly what I wanted. If I use the method `mesh.getPoints(mypoints, MSpace::kWorld)` the retrieved positions that are supposed to be in world space, are (0 0 0 0) for every vertex in a single polyplane. If I use default MSpace, I get the local positions correctly. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It could happen if you've got a degenerate transform (scaled to zero on the two axes defining the plane, for example).  You're doing C++ - what does the MStatus return say?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It returned `Error: (kInvalidParameter): Must have a DAG path to do world space transforms`. So I had to use `MFnMesh fnmesh(dagpath)` instead of the `meshnode` in order to get the global coordinates when using `fnmesh.getPoints(...)`